# Repeating batch script

Tags: command-line, batch

I'm having some problems with the below batch script I wrote that's named "**Options.bat**" so I wanted to write about my challenges and see if anyone could offer me any help.

**My Script Design**

The script is designed to offer quick access to four options I use frequently:

1. Creating a folder called "**test**" in C drive
2. Opening **Internet Explorer**
3. Opening a folder called "**test**" in C drive
4. Opening **Devices and Printers** screen

---

**My Script Problems**

1. **Repeating** - I want to be able to choose an option and then have the script return to start so that another option can be chosen and so on until the user actually closes the command screen. Currently, only one action can be taken, then the command screen closes after pause
2. **Don't use options that aren't chosen** - At the moment, if option 4 is selected then only its logic runs. However, if option 1 is selected then it runs all the option's routine logic in sequential order.
3. I need to call this script from another script so I need to be sure this all works calling it via another script is possible or matters.

---

### My Batch Script

**Options.bat**

```
::Provides 4 action options
@ECHO OFF
C:
CD\
CLS

:MENU
CLS

ECHO ============= MENU NAME =============
ECHO -------------------------------------
ECHO 1.  Create "test" folder C drive
ECHO 2.  Open Internet Explorer
ECHO 3.  Open "test" folder
ECHO 4.  Open Devices and printers
ECHO ==========PRESS 'Q' TO QUIT==========
ECHO.

SET INPUT=
SET /P INPUT=Please select a number:

IF /I '%INPUT%'=='1' GOTO Selection1
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='2' GOTO Selection2
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='3' GOTO Selection3
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='4' GOTO Selection4
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='Q' GOTO Quit

CLS

ECHO ============INVALID INPUT============
ECHO -------------------------------------
ECHO Please select a number from the Main
echo Menu [1-4] or select 'Q' to quit.
ECHO -------------------------------------
ECHO ======PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE======

PAUSE > NUL
GOTO MENU

:Selection1

md c:\test

:Selection2

start iexplore

:Selection3

start c:\test

:Selection4

control printers

:Quit
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your logic below to run the way I'd write it per the way you explain you wish it to work.

> **Essentially this will. . .**
>
> - Use the [`CALL`](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) command to call the specified subroutine rather than `GOTO` since it will pass control
>     back to the subroutine that made the call originally as long as it end
>     with `GOTO :EOF`.
> - Use the `GOTO :EOF` at the end of each called subroutine to pass control back to the original caller subroutine so it can continue to process the rest
>     its logic

---

### Script

```
::Provides 4 action options
@ECHO OFF
C:
CD\
CLS

:MENU
CLS

ECHO ============= MENU NAME =============
ECHO -------------------------------------
ECHO 1.  Create "test" folder C drive
ECHO 2.  Open Internet Explorer
ECHO 3.  Open "test" folder
ECHO 4.  Open Devices and printers
ECHO ==========PRESS 'Q' TO QUIT==========
ECHO.

SET INPUT=
SET /P INPUT=Please select a number:

IF /I '%INPUT%'=='1' CALL :Selection1
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='2' CALL :Selection2
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='3' CALL :Selection3
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='4' CALL :Selection4
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='Q' CALL :Quit

CLS

ECHO ============INVALID INPUT============
ECHO -------------------------------------
ECHO Please select a number from the Main
echo Menu [1-4] or select 'Q' to quit.
ECHO -------------------------------------
ECHO ======PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE======

PAUSE > NUL
GOTO :MENU

:Selection1
md c:\test
GOTO :EOF

:Selection2
start iexplore
GOTO :EOF

:Selection3
start c:\test
GOTO :EOF

:Selection4
control printers
GOTO :EOF

:Quit
PAUSE
```

---

### Further Resources

- [Call](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html)

  - > **CALL a subroutine (:label)**
    >
    > The `CALL` command will pass control to the statement after the label
    >   specified along with any specified parameters. ***To exit the subroutine
    >   specify `GOTO :eof` this will transfer control to the end of the current
    >   subroutine***.

Answer (score 0):

so:

```
:Selection1

md c:\test

GOTO Quit
```

You have to skip to the end afterwards. If not, it will just continue with `Selection2`.

But if you want to restart the script to restart until the user selects 'Q', just make a GOTO that will go back to the selection.

In order to run it from another batch like "batchfile.bat 4", which will run Selection4, I added the function

```
::Provides 4 action options
@ECHO OFF
C:
CD\
CLS

::Will skip menu if argument passed.

IF /I %1=='1' GOTO Selection1
IF /I %1=='2' GOTO Selection2
IF /I %1=='3' GOTO Selection3
IF /I %1=='4' GOTO Selection4  

:MENU
CLS

ECHO ============= MENU NAME =============
ECHO -------------------------------------
ECHO 1.  Create "test" folder C drive
ECHO 2.  Open Internet Explorer
ECHO 3.  Open "test" folder
ECHO 4.  Open Devices and printers
ECHO ==========PRESS 'Q' TO QUIT==========
ECHO.

SET INPUT=
SET /P INPUT=Please select a number:

IF /I '%INPUT%'=='1' GOTO Selection1
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='2' GOTO Selection2
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='3' GOTO Selection3
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='4' GOTO Selection4
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='Q' GOTO Quit

CLS

ECHO ============INVALID INPUT============
ECHO -------------------------------------
ECHO Please select a number from the Main
echo Menu [1-4] or select 'Q' to quit.
ECHO -------------------------------------
ECHO ======PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE======

PAUSE > NUL
GOTO MENU

:Selection1

md c:\test
GOTO MENU

:Selection2

start iexplore
GOTO MENU

:Selection3

start c:\test
GOTO MENU    

:Selection4

control printers
GOTO MENU

:Quit
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `GOTO MENU` at the end of each `Selection` should solve the 1st and 2nd problems for you e.g.:

```
:Selection1

ECHO Option: "test" folder on C drive...
md c:\test
timeout /t 3 /nobreak > NUL
GOTO MENU

:Selection2

ECHO Option: Open Internet Explorer...
start iexplore
timeout /t 3 /nobreak > NUL
GOTO MENU

:Selection3

ECHO Option: Open "test" folder...
start c:\test
timeout /t 3 /nobreak > NUL
GOTO MENU

:Selection4

ECHO Option: Open Devices and printers...
control printers
timeout /t 3 /nobreak > NUL
GOTO MENU

:Quit
PAUSE
```

In the code above, I have also added an `ECHO` statement (to clarify which option was selected) and a [timeout](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) in seconds (which delays the return to the `MENU`-- otherwise, the return is instantaneous). Neither of these are strictly necessary.

Note that the `> NUL` after `timeout` prevents a countdown (which is what `timeout` normally produces) from being displayed.

> If I call this script from another batch file, can I still use the repeating option mentioned at (1) from within the other script?

I believe the simple answer is "No" (at least not how I believe you intend this). Repeatedly sending input to the batch window might be possible through third party applications, however.